# Yii2: How to validate a form with AJAX and then submit the data using AJAX again

Tags: php, ajax, validation, submit, yii2

I can't find a way in Yii2 for the following:

1. First validate my form via AJAX because I have a UNIQUE field.
2. Then if the validation is correct submit the form data to the form action via AJAX.

Here is what I got so far:

In my view:

```
<?php
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'subscribe-form',
            'action' => ['site/subscribe'],
            'validationUrl' => ['site/validate-subscribe'],
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->input('text', ['class' => 'w-input']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->input('text', ['class' => 'w-input']) ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('SUSCRIBIRSE', ['class' => 'w-inline-block btn', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
        </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

In my controller:

```
public function actionValidateSubscribe(){
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $model = new Subscription(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams()['Subscription']);

        if (!$model->validate()) {
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    }
}

public function actionSubscribe()
{

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $model = new Subscription(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams()['Subscription']);

        if(!$model->validate()){
            throw new NotAcceptableHttpException('Tiene errores de validación en la forma');
        }



        if($model->save()){
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('subscription', ['model'=>$model])
                ->setTo([$model->name => $model->email])
                ->setFrom(['Test' => 'info@test.com'])
                ->setSubject('Por favor confirme su suscripción')
                ->send();
        }

        $response = [
            'data'=>$model->getAttributes(),
            'success'=>'true'
        ];
        return $response;
    }
}
```

In my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('body').on('beforeSubmit', 'form#subscribe-form', function () {
    var form = $(this);
    // return false if form still have some validation errors
    if (form.find('.has-error').length) {
        return false;
    }

    // submit form
    $.ajax({
        url    : form.attr('action'),
        type   : 'post',
        data   : form.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            // do something with response
        },
        error  : function () {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

The problem is that yii.ActiveForm.js is not triggering the afterVAlidate or beforeSubmit events when I set "enableAjaxValidation" to true in my ActiveForm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$('form#subscribe-form').on('beforeSubmit', function () {...});`